# Efficient Duplicate Checker in Clojure

Tags: clojure, performance

I'm looking for a way do efficiently determine duplicate (by md5) files in a directory, and create a collection of maps with a ":unique" file and a vector of ":other" files. The code I have below can achieve this on 2919 files in about 46 seconds (45948ms).

This code works, but there must be a quicker way.. How can I alter my code to get a bit more performance?

```
(def extensions [".mp3" ".wav" ".mp4" ".flac" ".aac"])

(defn valid? [file]
  "returns true when the file is not a directory and ends in one of the specified extensions"
  (and (not (.isDirectory file))
       (some true? (map #(.endsWith (.getName file) %) extensions))))

(defn file->file+hash [file]
  "returns a map of the filepath and the files md5"
  {:hash (d/md5 file) :path (.getAbsolutePath file)})

(defn split [[x & more]] 
  {:unique (:path x) :other (vec (map :path more))})

(defn get-dictionary [file-directory]
  "returns a map of maps, each of which contain a ':unique' file and a vector of ':other' files"
  (let [files (filter valid? (file-seq (f/file file-directory)))]
    (map split (vals (group-by :hash (pmap file->file+hash files))))))

(def location "/home/matt/Music/Playlists")
(prn (str "Files: " (count (file-seq (f/file location)))))
(time (get-dictionary location))

"Files: 2919"
"Elapsed time: 45948.444212 msecs"
```

Comment: I should mention that the "d/md5" comes from clj-digest. "d" is the alias

Comment: Use a faster hash algorithm? CRC-Whatever should be better that MD5 for your purposes, for instance. Other than that I'm guessing the bottleneck will be disk reads.

Comment: Have you profiled your code, so you know what parts of it are slow? It would be silly to recommend micro-optimizations if 99% of the time is waiting for your disk to spin.

Comment: How can i determine how much file io is contributing to the time?

Comment: @merb have you tried simply slurping the files to see how long just the file disk reading takes? Or hashing random byte arrays in memory to determine how fast your hashing works?

Comment: @merb Use a Java profiler to see how much CPU time is spent in each method. VisualVM is a good starting point, as it comes bundled with the JDK. I expect you'll find that the majority of time is spent in the `md5` function, in which case @dsm's comment is relevant.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to profile the code, but switching to CRC32 decreased the time by about 7 seconds (39094ms). Thank you for the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try doing an initial compare on something known, like the filesize, instead of the hash. If you expect most of your files to be unique, this would save a lot of time calculating hashes for all your files.